# Android tabs: add custom state besides "selected"

Tags: android, android-tabs

Normally there's nothing but one selector for tabs: either it is selected or not. I need to add an attribute to put a small mark on certain tabs depending on their fragments' content. For tabs I use [SmartTabLayout](https://github.com/ogaclejapan/SmartTabLayout) library. 
Any ideas if it is possible and how? What means can I use to put a mark below tab text and its background?

Comment: use latest api version 22.2.1. and use this, https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32 with selector. it will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use Tabs indicator

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_focus" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_press" />
</selector>
```

And check

```
android:state_pressed="true"
```